# Can you set the RSA public exponent to a value of your choice?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

[This](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml) website describes a way to implement RSA in java using a library. Is it possible to have control over the value of the public exponent e? Java sets it to 65537. I know that it is an appropriate value but can I change it while still using the library?

This is how they implement it:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPublicKeySpec pub = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(),
RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPrivate(),
RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

saveToFile("public.key", pub.getModulus(),
pub.getPublicExponent());
saveToFile("private.key", priv.getModulus(),
priv.getPrivateExponent());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you should be certain that it is a prime number (bounded by the size of the modulus):

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
// 17 is another often used value, beware to use proper RSA padding if you set it to 3
RSAKeyGenParameterSpec kpgSpec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, BigInteger.valueOf(3));
kpg.initialize(kpgSpec);
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
```

Note that you cannot change it after key generation. Also note that if your exponent is too large (or has many bits set to 1) that it will affect the speed of public key operations. 65537 - the default - is a good value that has only 2 bits set to 1 (the fourth number of Fermat, or F4).

Comment: There's also Microsoft's old CAPI limit of 32 bits, which is important if you want to interoperate with .NET software.

Comment: @GregS There is a small light in the back of my head telling me that I heard of this limit before. No need for large exponents anyway, but good additional info.